# How can I enable workflows for comments?

Tags: 9, comments, workflows

I would like to create workflows for comments and moderate them, but I can't find comments under *This workflow applies to:* on /admin/config/workflow/workflows/manage/comment_workflow.

Does anyone know how I can enable workflows on comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Without a module that implements workflows for the Comment entity, you cannot.

The *Workflow* module doesn't implement any workflow: It's an API module other modules can use to implement their workflows.
An example of this is the *Content moderation* module, the only Drupal core module that implements workflows. Its workflows only apply to *Custom block types* and *Content types*, as shown in /admin/config/workflow/workflows/manage/editorial.

> [image: screenshot]

Even when you create a new *Content moderation* workflow, *Comment types* isn't an option listed under *This workflow applies to*.